# SQL : Apply filter based on the user selection and Filter should match all the values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where i have to Apply filter based on the user selection and Filter should match all the values.
Ex: If user apply the filter for Hotel Amenities it should filter hotel that match all the Amenities selected by User.

### HotelID AmenitiesID

```
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       4
3       2
3       3
```

> ```
> Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetHotelListing]
> @HotelID INT = 1,
> @Amenities varchar(50) = '1,3'
> AS
> BEGIN
> select  * from DTHotelAmenities where HotelID = @HotelID and <Searching For Condition>
> END
> ```

Comment: Look at table valued type parameters or dynamic sql.

Comment: Can you please suggest some query

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic query version:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetHotelListing]
@HotelID INT = 1,
@Amenities varchar(50) = '1,3'
AS
BEGIN

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
     'select  * from DTHotelAmenities where HotelID = ' + 
      cast(@HotelID as nvarchar(max)) + 
      ' and AmenitiesID in(' + @Amenities + ')'

     exec(@sql)

END
```

In general beware of possibility of sql injection threat. You may want to look at `sp_executesql` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like....

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetHotelListing]
@HotelID INT = 1,
@Amenities varchar(50) = '1,3'
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  Declare @xml XML;
  Declare @t table (ID INT);

  SET @xml = '<root><x>' +  REPLACE(@Amenities , ',' , '</x><x>')  + '</x></root>'

INSERT INTO @t(ID)
Select r.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') value
FROM @xml.nodes('//root/x') as records(r)

select  o.* 
from DTHotelAmenities o
INNER JOIN @t t ON t.ID = o.AmenitiesID
where o.HotelID = @HotelID

END
```

Comment: I should add if you remove the Where statement, you can see all hotels which have amenities if x,t x

Comment: @JohnCappelletti the OP is passing the HotelID as a param too isnt he ??

Comment: In my little head, it is completely optional.  Let's say you wanted a list of hotels in Providence that have free WI-FI.